# Backshift with a past continuous

Tags: verbs, backshifting

Is it correct when using reported speech to say: Jan said that on the weekend she cycled and went hiking rather than Jan said that on the weekend she cycled and had gone hiking?

Tks Jan

Comment: The second one with *had gone* doesn’t sound right.

Comment: What is the original sentence you are reporting?

Answer (score -1):

You'll be understood anyway. So if your primary concern is to be understood , then both sentences are ok. Personally I'd use the first.

I'd say that the perfect tense is just superfluous.  The first is way better.  My suggestion to you is that you shouldn't make it too difficult for yourself trying to figure out 'whether or not  I should use the perfect here'. English is about flexibility. It's definitely not about grammar.